# Xdocument.Load gives NotSupported exception

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2010, xmldocument

I have been using XDocument in my windows phone app to load xml files.It never gave any problem reading .xml files. but recently I had to add more data to one of my xml files. It was of size 16kb and now it is of 76kb. After this change the load function started throwing a exception (NotSupportedException) . Is the size of the file the reason for this? How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Can you give the *full* details of the exception? I'd expect the message - and the stack trace - to give more hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I just found why it wasn't able to parse. I had to replace all the '&' signs I used with 'and'.

Comment: I think you should close this question